# Does Salesforce2Salesforce Support Delete?

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I am exploring a Salesforce2Salesforce integration. Insert, update seems to be working properly between the Org but when a record gets deleted in the parent org, the same is not getting Synced with partner Org. I am getting `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` when I try to do the Sync. Does Salesforce2Salesforce work for delete scenario?

Comment: Looks like salesforce to salesforce doesnt have a deletion sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practices_for_Salesforce_to_Salesforce) says that you can do this automatically in the child org using batch APEX.

> Challenge: Delete Case comments from the target org if Case comments
>   in the source org are made private or deleted.
>
> Solution: In an Apex batch, check the PartnerNetworkRecordConnection,
>   locate the record connection status, and delete the local record if
>   the shared record from the source org is deleted. Schedule the batch
>   to run every hour. The Salesforce.com UI does not permit scheduling to
>   less than a weekly or monthly frequency. To schedule the following
>   batch programatically, you can create a Visualforce page and call Apex
>   code to do the scheduling (the code sample is below the batch code.)

Comment: Thank you. Looks like batch based approach is the only way